# 'Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments' in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore with flutter. I am constantly getting this error and not able to solve it despite reading all available reference.Can Someone please help me solve the problem.
My Code -

```
String uid = '+919101006470';
final snapShot = await db.collection("users").document(uid).get();
```

The error is

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1, null)

Comment: Please edit the question to show the exact string value for `uid`.

Comment: Actually uid is the user's phone number I have used. The document id is the phone number of the user.

Comment: Could you edit the question to share that actual string value? Without it, we can only guess what's going on.  We need the actual value.

Comment: I have edited it now.

Comment: The doesn't look like it will generate the error you're seeing.  Are you absolutely sure that's the string value for `uid` that causes this error?  If it is, file a bug with flutterfire.  https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire

Comment: Yes, I am sure about the String Value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause of the error is quite simple, you have a path with an uneven number of segments, which means it points to a **collection** and not to a document.

The easiest way to troubleshoot is to print the path of the document reference before calling `get()` on it:

```
final ref = db.collection("users").document(uid).get();
print (ref.path);
final snapShot = await ref;
```

As Doug commented, on the code you gave it seems most likely that `uid` doesn't have a value, but printing the path will show you which segment of your path is empty/missing.

Comment: I tried checking for the path but it all seems to be working fine.

Comment: Output - ```users/+919101006470```

Comment: In that case it seems very unlikely that the error is coming from the code you shared. Are you sure there isn't another place where you are creating a document reference?